# How to convert moment date to a string and remove the moment object

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, momentjs

I have a React Web App and a React Native Mobile App. When I pass a moment date object from my react web app to my backend, it gets converted to a string somehow and it works with my backend.

When I do it with my react native mobile app, it passes the date as a moment object and it doesn't get converted to a string and it doesn't work.

Is there a way to convert the moment object into a plain string like

```
"Tue May 05 2015 23:59:59 GMT+0800 (HKT)"
```

I tried toString() and toUTCString() and it doesn't work. Thanks.

Comment: Just try format function if that helps http://momentjs.com/docs/#/displaying/format/

Comment: @shinon
 You can try this
   var p = moment(new Date()).format("YYYY-MM-DD HH:mm:ssZ");  

  console.log(p);
  console.log(typeof(p));
  string

Answer (score 34, accepted):

Use [`moment().format()`](https://momentjs.com/docs/#/displaying/format/) to create a formatted string from the date.

```js
console.log(moment().format())
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment.js/2.18.1/moment.js"></script>
```

But if you're using version 2.1.0+ ([link](http://momentjs.com/docs/#/displaying/as-string/)), `toString` should work:

```js
console.log(moment().toString())
console.log(typeof moment().toString())
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment.js/2.18.1/moment.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 10):

You're trying to call methods that only exist on a javascript `Date` object. In order to call those methods you'd need to first convert the `Moment` object into a plain `Date` object. You can use the [`.toDate()`](https://momentjs.com/docs/#/displaying/as-javascript-date/) method on the Moment object to do this.

```js
var plainDate = moment().toDate();
console.log(plainDate.toUTCString());
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment.js/2.18.1/moment.js"></script>
```

However, a more direct way of converting a Moment object to a string is to use the [`.format()`](https://momentjs.com/docs/#/displaying/format/) method, which will output as "ISO 8601" standard that looks like `2014-09-08T08:02:17-05:00`.

```js
console.log( moment().format() );
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment.js/2.18.1/moment.js"></script>
```