# momentjs returns an object

Tags: javascript, reactjs, momentjs

I am trying to format date time string value using react-moment in my react component. moment returns an object but i need a string value from moment.
This is the code I have:

```
import Moment from 'react-moment';

const dateToFormat = '2015-08-31T16:14:00.000Z';

const datetm = <Moment format="dddd, MMMM Do YYYY, h:mm a" date = {dateToFormat} />;
```

`datetm` always return object but I want it to be string. Does moment has any attribute that can be set to get string value instead an object?

Comment: You can just use the format object to set it as a string `moment(dateToFormat).format('dddd, MMMM Do YYYY');`

Comment: https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-moment#formatting

Comment: I think you can get reference from below https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45809080/how-to-convert-moment-date-to-a-string-and-remove-the-moment-object

Comment: If you don't want a React element why are you creating one?

Comment: when i use moment(dateToFormat).format('dddd, MMMM Do YYYY');
 it throws error 'Cannot call a class as a function'. @fleix I have to format a dateToFormat value in different formats

Comment: I think you are using the wrong library. What you need for this is http://momentjs.com/ . react-moment is a react wrapper for momentjs.

Comment: *"I have to format a dateToFormat value in different formats"* That is not a reason to create or not create a React component. You are either using React and want to render a date with React or you don't.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are using react-moment which is a wrapper component for the moment js. You can you use this as a react component. but not as normal use. Instead use moment js.

install the moment js package using npm.

`> npm install --save moment`

in your js file

`> import moment from 'moment';`

then use moment instance.

```
> moment(<date string>/<date object>/<moment object>).format(<format string>)
```